# Mock function with class template parameter in signature

Tags: c++, testing, mocking, googlemock

Is it possible with gmock to mock a function which contains a class template parameter in it's signature? For example:

```
template <typename T>
struct Mockable
{
    virtual void do_work(const int num, const T& value) = 0;
};

template <typename T>
struct MockMockable : Mockable<T>
{
    MOCK_METHOD2(do_work, void(const int, const T&));
};
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I found the answer, you need to denote the mock methods specifically as template mock methods with a `_T`

```
template <typename T>
struct MockMockable : Mockable<T>
{
    MOCK_METHOD2_T(do_work, void(const int, const T&));
};
```

More information:
https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/gmock_cheat_sheet.md#mocking-a-class-template-mocktemplate